# Difference in dates grouped by users and product mysql

Tags: mysql, jupyter-notebook

I have the following table:

| id | date | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 2022-01-01 | A |
| 001 | 2022-01-03 | B |
| 001 | 2022-01-02 | B |
| 001 | 2022-02-02 | A |
| 002 | 2022-01-01 | A |
| 002 | 2022-01-03 | B |
| 004 | 2022-01-01 | A |
| 004 | 2022-01-03 | B |

And I need to sort the dates decending, group by ID and Type and get the time between the dates by ID and Type, either in seconds or months days

| id | date | type | time diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 2022-01-01 | A | 0 |
| 001 | 2022-01-02 | B | 1 |
| 001 | 2022-01-03 | B | 1 |
| 001 | 2022-02-02 | A | 31 |
| 002 | 2022-01-01 | A | 0 |
| 002 | 2022-01-03 | B | 2 |
| 004 | 2022-01-01 | A | 0 |
| 004 | 2022-01-03 | B | 2 |

Answer (score 1):

We can use `DATEDIFF()` here along with the `LAG()` analytic function:

```sql
SELECT id, date, type,
       DATEDIFF(date, LAG(date, 1, date) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date)) AS diff
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY id, date;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MySQL 8.0,window functions are strongly recommended. Otherwise,you might have to go a long way. Here is the query written and tested in workbench using 5.7 :

```
select tb1.id,tb1.date,tb1.type,ifnull(datediff(tb1.date,tb2.date),0) as 'time diff'
from
    (select id,date,type, @row_id:=@row_id+1 as row_id
    from
        (select id,date,type
        from test
        group by id,date,type
        order by id,date)t1,
        (select @row_id:=0) t
    ) tb1
left join
    (select id,date,type, @row_num:=@row_num+1 as row_num
    from
        (select id,date,type
        from test
        group by id,date,type
        order by id,date)t2,
        (select @row_num:=0) t
    ) tb2
on tb1.id=tb2.id and tb1.row_id-tb2.row_num=1
order by tb1.id,tb1.date
;
```